# CSS - Prevent The Text From Moving When Resizing

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have this simple HTML DIV where the word "Loading" is in the middle.
I also have the JavaScript code to change the dots in the `#waitDotDotDot` element.

```js
var dots = window.setInterval( function() {
  var wait = document.getElementById("waitDotDotDot");
  if ( wait.innerHTML.length > 5 ) 
    wait.innerHTML = "";
  else 
    wait.innerHTML += ".";
}, 300);
```

```html
<div style="width: 90%; text-align:center; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; border: 1px solid black;">
  <div style="margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; width:90%;">
    Loading <span id="waitDotDotDot">.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is working, but it keeps resizing the "Loading" text (pushing it to the left) when the numbers of dots is increasing. Is there a way to keep the "Loading" text in the same position (still center), but only the dots are resizing while it is increasing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this kind of effect, personally I'd forego the script to keep it simple and solve the issue at the same time.

```css
.container {
  border: green 1px dashed;
}

.dotme {
  margin-left: calc(50% - 4rem); 
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: inline;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: red 1px dotted;
}

.dotme:after {
  content: "\2026";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: bottom;     
  animation: dots steps(4,end) .75s infinite alternate;  
}

@keyframes dots {
  to { width: 3rem;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside class="dotme">Loading</aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow.  I didn't know that CSS can doing something like that.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, it didn't work.  If I put that inside parent div with `text-align:center;` it behaves the same "Loading " is pushing the left when the dot (.) is increasing.  Can you please change your snipped sample to center the "Loading ..."

Comment: @Milacay oooh ok, sorry that's what I get for speeding questions, hang on let me finish my real work and will show ya how to mitigate that too. That's expected from a inline-block transform.

Comment: So like @Skylar pointed out, there's loads of ways to accomplish this without script. Another simple technique is applied in the edited example. I wasn't sure where you considered 'center' since it could be technically 'centered' with or without the ellipsis at the end and look off one way or another so just adjust the calc as needed. Hope it helps, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I modified Chris W.'s post to achieve the desired result.

```css
.divWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.loading {
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dots {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.dots::before {
  content: "\2026";
  visibility: visible;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  animation: dots steps(4,end) 1s infinite forwards;
}

@keyframes dots {
  to { width: 2.5rem;}
}
```

```html
<div class="divWrapper">
  <p class="loading">
    Loading<span class="dots">&#x2026;</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: So a couple tips. Generally don't double up between unicode usage in both the pseudo element and the direct content, can cause issues. Also for cross-browser considerations always supply a default top/left when using position absolute (helpful info if you ever have to support internet explorer 11 and before) and it's handy knowing visibility:hidden always retains the height/width etc properties as a node in the DOM even though not visible so that was pretty clever! +1 and cheers!

Comment: Thank you @Skylar